# How will sort method do a sort, on a list that contains objects of type Foo?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, linked-list

How will a `LinkedList` of type :

```
LinkedList<FooClass> list = new LinkedList<FooClass>();

// FooClass extends Comparable

list.add(foo_obj_1);
list.add(foo_obj_2);
list.add(foo_obj_3);
list.add(foo_obj_4);
```

be sorted by :

```
Collection.sort(list);
```

What effect will `sort` method have on `list` that contains a list of objects.On what basis will the list be sorted ?

Comment: Didn't realize that the Java API was down and couldn't be reached for review. Bummer as this is all well explained there.

Answer (score 0):

If you make you an object `comparable`, then you override the `compareTo` method. You can then write your own custom criteria based on what fields you want to compare. A sort can then be performed as usual.

```
class Author implements Comparable<Author>{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Author other){
        int last = this.lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);
        return last == 0 ? this.firstName.compareTo(other.firstName) : last;
    }
}
```

If your object does not implement `Comparable` then you will not be able to perform any of the various sort implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the API of [`Collections#sort(List<T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-). It will only compile if T extends Comparable.

If `Foo` does not extend `Comparable`, your code will not compile.
If it does, the list will be sorted by Foo's natural ordering, as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).